# noob, java spring autowired hibernate mysql query, is this right?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm working on a small program that lists local train stops in a numbered list then asks for the user to type the number of the station that they wish to see the next arrival time for.

The problem I have is I don't think the MySQL query is correct to retrieve the arrival time. The list returns empty. Using jdbc previously, this query worked fine:

```
"SELECT arrival_time FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id = '"
+ myStation.getID()
+ "' AND arrival_time > time('now', 'localtime') ORDER BY arrival_time asc;";
```

And the current hibernate query:

```
public List<String> getArrivals() {
    sessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    String sql = "SELECT arrival_time FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id = '"
       + myStation.getID()
       + "' AND arrival_time > time('now', 'localtime') ORDER BY arrival_time asc;";

    Query query = sessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession()
       .createSQLQuery(sql)
       .addEntity(Station.class);

    List<String> arrivals = query.list();

    sessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    return arrivals;

}
```

Called from this method and where I get *IndexOutOfBoundsException*:

```
public String getNextArrival(int user_input) {

    getStationName(user_input);


    List<String> arrivals1 = arrival.getArrivals();

    System.out.println(arrivals1);
    System.out.println(arrivals1.size());

    String arrivalTime = arrivals1.get(user_input);
    return convertTime(arrivalTime);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException**: Index: 0, 
>       Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>       at com.moeller.code.Stops.getNextArrival(Stops.java:73)
>
> Line 73    String arrivalTime = arrivals1.get(user_input);'

The DataBase is stored locally.

Comment: did you executed the sql in mysql ?

Comment: You really, really need to learn and use prepared statements (or parameterized JPQL queries): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Comment: also what is the table structure of `stop_times` ?

Comment: ive executed it in sqlite, it does work. I didnt know if hibernate didnt like it for some reason, first time using it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this.

First, the query does not use parameters, which means you will likely make this mistake elsewhere where it will be a danger. You have to pass on variables like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT arrival_time FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id = ?"
   + " AND arrival_time > time('now', 'localtime') ORDER BY arrival_time asc;";

Query query = sessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession()
   .createSQLQuery(sql)
   .addEntity(Station.class);

query.setParameter(1, myStation.getID());
```

See the question mark? That is a positional parameter. You can also use named parameters.

```
String sql = "SELECT thing FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE :ptrn";
...
query.setParameter("ptrn", "%that%");
```

Notice how inside the query the parameter starts with `:`, but it does not when calling `setParameter`.

This way of safely inserting parameters is called using "Prepared Statements", or "Parameterized Queries". Find a quick tutorial on them, they are very important.

Secondly, in `getNextArrival` you forget to check if the list has that many elements.

```
if (arrivals1.size() <= user_input) {
     return null;
}
```

Of course then you have to be careful when it returns a null to the function where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong method for the List.

when yo use `List.get(param)` param should be the position that you are looking for, no the userInput.

you need  loop the list and compare each position of the list with the user input.

best Regards